# Python: What does this expression mean '^ '[True] or '^ '[False]

Tags: python

I was watching Brandon Rhodes talk on Dictionary where I found him using a generator expression

```
diff = ('^ '[a==b] for a,b in zip(k1, k2))
```

where `k1` and `k2` are binary representations of some numbers. For every bit in `k1` and `k2` which are not identical this generator expression puts a `'^ '` to mark the position. I haven't been able to understand this expression. What it means?

Comment: Especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/470376/1903116) in the linked question.

Comment: That's a 'hidden' conditional expression; the Python boolean type is a subclass of `int` and `False` has the numeric value `0`, `True` has the numeric value `1`, so based on that either `'^'` or `' '` is picked.

Comment: Hint: try `'^ '[False]` and then `'^ '[True]` in the interactive shell.

Comment: The code would be much improved with an actual conditional expression: `(' ' if a == b else '^' for a, b in zip(k1, k2))`.